# Differentiation of functional

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative

For $u=u(t,x), v=v(t,x)$, does the following equation hold? And why?

$$\partial_x \int_{0}^{v} \left(\int_{0}^{t}u(s,x)ds \right) du
 = \partial_x v\int_{0}^{t}v(s,x)ds$$

---

Here's what I thought. If I define

$$G(u) := \int_{0}^{t}u(s,x)ds$$

using formula for differentiation of integrals,

$$\partial_x\int_{0}^{v}G(u)du=(\partial_xv)G(v)$$

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) will answer your question ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So it equals $(∂_x v)G(v)+\int_{0}^{v}∂_x G(u)du$ and the equation above doesn't hold..?